# Is there a way to set referencing outlet in Interface Builder without Ctrl-Drag

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode4.3

So I'm just trying to create a very simple app for demo purposes here:

- Created a Single View Application, using storyboards
- Added a UIView to the storyboard
- Added the following code to my controller's header file:

  ```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
  ```

Now, I understand that I can link the UIView to the controller by:

- arranging my code such that the header file is next to the storyboard
- holding down Ctrl key and dragging it to the property in the header file

My question is this: can I do this **without** Ctrl-drag? And if so, how?

More specifically - it's annoying to have to put both my header file and storyboard on screen at the same time, and it seems there should be a way to make this connection without doing so.

I also understand that I can manually place the view by creating it inside my controller's viewDidLoad function, but I'd really like to use the interface builder to simplify / visualize things.

**Edit:** Is the answer to my question affected whether I use storyboards or xib/nib files?  (I'd switch to use the one where it works)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Dima's answer, you can just as well use the Connection inspector in the Utilities pane

[image: Connection Inspector]

Comment: Thanks - it took me a while to figure out it's not just "click on the referencing outlet and something will popup", but I have to drag the connection to my view in IB.

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to right click the element, and drag the "referencing outlet" item to the view's "File's Owner" in interface builder. There, it will give you a list of all available IBOutlets (matching the object's type).

Comment: I was about to say "I can't right click", but it looks like part of my problem is that my external mouse connected via Synergy is translating "Right Click" to "Left Click" - I'm on a Macbook, so I have to 'two-finger' click  on the trackpad to get a 'right click'.  This helps; thanks :)